# Execute a function when the page is loaded angular

Tags: angularjs

I have this function selectHotel() which executes when the select box is clicked and I have used GET method to call data and display it on my view.

I have two options on my select area and it fetches different data for both of them. I want the data of my first option to be displayed when the page is loaded and not when I click the select box.

```
<div class="row">
            <div class ="form_group">
                <select ng-click="selectHotel()" class="form-control" ng-options='item as item.hotel_name for item in hotels.data' ng-model='current_Hotel'></select>
                Check In:<input type="date">
                Check Out:<input type="date">
            </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">      
            <h1>{{current_Hotel.hotel_name}}</h1>
            <p>{{current_Hotel.hotel_description}}</p>
            <img id="hotelImg" class="img img-responsive" ng-src="{{current_Hotel.image_url}}">
            <btn class="btn btn-primary">Book a room </btn>
        </div>

    </div>

        <div class="row" ng-repeat="x in roomdata.data">
            <div class="well well-sm" >{{x.room_type}}<a href="#" class="pull-right">Room Details</a>
            </div>
            <h5>{{x.rack_price}}<br>Per room per night</h5>
            Adult: <select>
                <option>1</option>
                <option selected="selected">{{x.max_people}}</option>
            </select>
            Child: <select>
                <option>{{x.max_child}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Here is the controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl1', function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.current_Hotel = {
        hotel_id: "",
        hotel_name: "",
        hotel_description: "",
        exterior_image: "",
        image_url: ""
    };

    $http({
        url: '',
        method: "POST",
        data: 'postData',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': ''
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
                $scope.hotels = response.data;
                $scope.current_Hotel = $scope.hotels.data[0];
            });       

    $scope.selectHotel = function () {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '&image_id=' + $scope.current_Hotel.exterior_image
        }).then(function (response) {

                var imgdata = response.data;
                var imgdata1 = imgdata.data.image_name;
                $scope.current_Hotel.image_url = "" + imgdata1;
            });

         $http({
            method:'GET',
            url: '&hotel_id=' +$scope.current_Hotel.hotel_id
        }).then(function(response){
            $scope.roomdata = response.data;
        });

    };
});
```

Comment: You can directly call that first option function when page load.

Comment: are you basically willing to select first item in the select box by default ?

Comment: The first item in the select box is selected by default. But the item's additional data isn't called until I click on the select box. I want the first item's additional data to be called when the page is loaded and when I select the second option, It should display the second item's data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTMl to invoke a `changeHotel` when different option is selected.

Invoke `changeHotel` after all the hotels are loaded passing the first item in the hotel list. This will load the data for the first hotel as per your necessity.

**HTML:**

```
<select ng-options="hotel as hotel.name for hotel in hotels" 
        ng-model="currentHotel" 
        ng-change="changeHotel(currentHotel)">
</select>

<p>{{disp}}</p>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$http.get('API_URL')
  .then(function(res) {

    $scope.hotels = res.data;
    $scope.currentHotel = res.data[0];

    $scope.changeHotel($scope.currentHotel);

  });

$scope.changeHotel = function(hotel) {
  $scope.currentHotel = hotel;
  $scope.disp = "This is data for current hotel : " + $scope.currentHotel.name;
  // stuffs ...
};
```

Check this [**CodePen Demo**](http://codepen.io/prashantghimire/pen/LWeZpv?editors=1011)

Comment: Check this codepen demo ... let me know whats missing . http://codepen.io/prashantghimire/pen/Mprewr

Comment: Now i look at you code again ... try invoking `$scope.selectHotel()` 
after `$scope.current_Hotel = $scope.hotels.data[0];` line ...

Comment: Tried.Still dosen't work. I have edited my view. The part where I have used ng-repeat is only displayed when I click on the select area. I have used ng-init instead of ng-click but then the additional data is not being displayed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138383/discussion-between-prashant-ghimire-and-slash).